# Zxing library integration within tab

Tags: android, customization, qr-code, zxing

I was working with the Zxing library integration to an app. At first I was using a button to instantiate scan, so I was using Intent Integrator, then I thought of including the scan view inside my tab. (android.support.v4.app.Fragment). now I could not use the intentIntegrator as I need the 'CaptureActivity' to be invoked when the user clicks the QR tab. I some how managed to lock the QR tab to landscape (made a OntabChange listener and always made to keep the app in landscape for QR tab).
Now I have a custom view in one of the tabs,and 'SOME TIMES' a 'ADD button image'(used in my custom view) appears on the scan view which makes it impossible to scan anything. 
Is there anything you guys have to comment on this, I know it was not a good idea to work on your codes, I was so curious that I was not able to stop myself, sorry. 
Im screwed now, I have tried my app on the Samsung Galaxy tab and Adam tablet(with a cracked 2.2). both have the above scenario appearing and disappearing in the first launch of the app, it works fine in Samsung galaxy tab when I go to the native Camera and take a snap and come back..but in the Adam tablet the native Camera just don't open at all.

Thanks in advance
Happy coding